# Extended SUMPRODUCT formula needing to be compacted

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, sumproduct

I have this quite extended SUMPRODUCT formula in excel I want to make cleaner.

This is the initial question and my code below:
Assume that all stocks trade at their mid-price; i.e. halfway between high and low. Can you find the difference in value traded of these three stocks on a Friday as compared to a Monday (using just one sumproduct formula)?

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(--("BHP"=$A$2:$A$80),(($D$2:$D$80)-($E$2:$E$80))*($G$2:$G$80),--(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=6)))-(SUMPRODUCT(--("BHP"=$A$2:$A$80),(($D$2:$D$80)-($E$2:$E$80))*($G$2:$G$80),--(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=2)))+(SUMPRODUCT(--("ANZ"=$A$2:$A$80),(($D$2:$D$80)-($E$2:$E$80))*($G$2:$G$80),--(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=6)))-(SUMPRODUCT(--("ANZ"=$A$2:$A$80),(($D$2:$D$80)-($E$2:$E$80))*($G$2:$G$80),--(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=2)))+(SUMPRODUCT(--("FMG"=$A$2:$A$80),(($D$2:$D$80)-($E$2:$E$80))*($G$2:$G$80),--(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=6)))-(SUMPRODUCT(--("FMG"=$A$2:$A$80),(($D$2:$D$80)-($E$2:$E$80))*($G$2:$G$80),--(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=2)))
```

The series is this:

[image]

Comment: I think the short answer is 'no', you would need at least two sumproducts, one for Friday and one for Monday. However, it's too much data for anyone to type in to check their answer, so is it possible to provide some scaled-down test data that encapsulates the problem more concisely?

Comment: Or you may be able to use a website like this https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to convert your table to ASCII so people can copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, a shorter formula.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A80={"BHP","ANZ","FMG"})*((WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=6)-(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$80)=2))*($D$2:$D$80-$E$2:$E$80)*$G$2:$G$80)`